# Check if all value's in a array are int

Tags: php, arrays

Could not find a way to do this, but I'm looking for a way to check if all value's in an array are INT, if not it should return false.

Notice I cant sanitize the value's!

```
// the idea
$good = array(1,2,3,4);

$bad  = array(1,2,'no',4);

if($good){

   echo 'works';

}else{

   echo 'failed';

}
```

Comment: Loop through your array and use `in_int()` to check http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-int.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a reusable function you could use which will return false if any element of the array is not an int.

```
$bad  = array(1,2,'no',4);

CheckArray($bad);




function checkArray($array){

foreach($array as $value){
 if( ! is_int($value)){
    return false;
  }
 }
return true;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
array_reduce($arr, function ($result, $item) { return $result && is_int($item); }, true)
```

If you have some [functional programming primitives](https://github.com/lstrojny/functional-php), you can do:

```
if (every($arr, 'is_int')) ..
```

Comment: Good use for `array_reduce()`! But when the array is empty it returns true, now the question is if OP wants it like this or if it should return false on an empty array

Comment: True. If the array is empty, there's no obvious answer, so OP will have to handle this case separately anyway.

Comment: Just got an idea, since php 5.3+ `$initial` 3rd argument takes also mixed, so you can use this: `!empty($arr) && TRUE` as `$initial` argument, so if the array is empty it starts with `FALSE` and stays false otherwise it starts normal with `TRUE`

Comment: Yes, that'll do. Though you really should use `count()` instead of `empty`, or simply `!!$arr`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$bad  = array(1,2,'no',4);

foreach($bad as $value){
    if( ! is_int($value)){
        echo 'bad';
    }
}
```

Comment: Please explain to the OP (and future visitors to SO) why you did what you did.